# what is top-level document ? ( sharedArrayBuffer is not defined )

Tags: sharedarraybuffer, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

I was going to use `sharedArrayBuffer`. and I found that if cross-isolation was not established, it could not be used.

in document, both
`Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` and
`Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp`
should be set up in the top documents, but I don't know what the top-level documents are and how to set it up.

What should I do?

Comment: The top level document is the one opened directly in the tab, i.e the document that is not in an <iframe>.

Comment: then, how to set Cross-Origin on document?

Comment: Well, as you wrote in your question, you need both COOP same-origin and COEP require-corp HTTP response headers. Configure your server to set these headers.